# Bug with voting up and then down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I voted post up it became +3 then i changed my mind 
and decided to remove my vote -- it became 1.

Please fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is a problem with the site? Can you reproduce the behavior? Are you certain no-one else voted in the meantime?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce it yourself? Takes about 1.67 seconds. From my recollection i noticed this behavior about half a year ago.

Comment: FYI just reproduced same pattern on meta site. Firefox, Vista.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the post? Which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Did you click the upvote button again or did you click the downvote button? You should click the upvote button again.

Comment: I think you should add [meta-tag:support] to the question, and perhaps remove [meta-tag:bug]. . And maybe also [meta-tag:faq-proposed] should; be added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

If you have upvoted, then to clear your upvote click the upvote button again i.e. it acts as a toggle. If you click the downvote button it (a) undoes the upvote then (b) registers a downvote. Hence the -2 change.